# Python process scheduler simulator "Didn't select a process" bug

Tags: python, simulation, scheduler

So my code is a simulator of 4 process scheduling models, First come first served, shortest job first, round robin and shortest remaining time first. It runs 10 processes generated from a random seed, and then it's supposed to give diagnostics on how each model ran the processes. However, when I run my code, only first come first served works, and I get this error:

```
NOSE2 :: AE2 :: Scheduler Discrete Event Simulation
---------------------------------------------------
Using seed: 3122983877
Processes to be executed:
    [#0]: State: ProcessStates.NEW, Arrival: 0.4223112877404481, Service: 1.0263561382893103, Remaining: 1.0263561382893103
    [#1]: State: ProcessStates.NEW, Arrival: 0.6749794331092798, Service: 4.459858297198395, Remaining: 4.459858297198395
    [#2]: State: ProcessStates.NEW, Arrival: 0.8659040281652794, Service: 1.441062474365019, Remaining: 1.441062474365019
    [#3]: State: ProcessStates.NEW, Arrival: 1.4882627649754698, Service: 0.3537338775720223, Remaining: 0.3537338775720223
    [#4]: State: ProcessStates.NEW, Arrival: 1.8951836353944194, Service: 0.2799353896393308, Remaining: 0.2799353896393308
    [#5]: State: ProcessStates.NEW, Arrival: 1.9300794339524296, Service: 3.746867795097771, Remaining: 3.746867795097771
    [#6]: State: ProcessStates.NEW, Arrival: 2.606397084292392, Service: 5.415923226456155, Remaining: 5.415923226456155
    [#7]: State: ProcessStates.NEW, Arrival: 2.621462261146853, Service: 2.8116170876900024, Remaining: 2.8116170876900024
    [#8]: State: ProcessStates.NEW, Arrival: 2.8822626299616867, Service: 0.5817433587233805, Remaining: 0.5817433587233805
    [#9]: State: ProcessStates.NEW, Arrival: 2.9456451310810867, Service: 1.9047956931475214, Remaining: 1.9047956931475214
-----
FCFS [#Processes: 10, Avg arrivals per time unit: 3.0, Avg CPU burst time: 2, Context switch time: 0.0]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cochr\Downloads\ae2 code - Copy\ae2 code\main.py", line 70, in <module>
    sim.run(seed)
  File "c:\Users\cochr\Downloads\ae2 code - Copy\ae2 code\schedulers.py", line 40, in run
    super().run(seed)
  File "c:\Users\cochr\Downloads\ae2 code - Copy\ae2 code\des.py", line 185, in run
    raise ValueError("Scheduler didn't select any process to run!!!")
ValueError: Scheduler didn't select any process to run!!!
```

Here is my code for the Schedulers:

```
import math

from des import SchedulerDES
from event import Event, EventTypes
from process import ProcessStates

class FCFS(SchedulerDES):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = []

    def scheduler_func(self, cur_event):
        # FCFS scheduling logic
        if cur_event.event_type == EventTypes.PROC_ARRIVES:
            # If a process arrives, add it to the queue
            self.queue.append(cur_event.process_id)

    def dispatcher_func(self, cur_process):
        # FCFS dispatching logic
        if cur_process is not None:
            self.log_info("Dispatching process #{}".format(cur_process.process_id))
            cur_process.process_state = ProcessStates.RUNNING
            time_executed = cur_process.run_for(cur_process.remaining_time, self.current_time)
            # Check if the process is completed
            if cur_process.remaining_time == 0:
                # If the process is completed, add it to the list of completed processes
                self.completed_processes.append(cur_process)
            else:
                # If the process is not completed, update the currently running process
                self.currently_running_process = cur_process
        else:
            self.log_info("No process to dispatch.")
            # If there is no process to dispatch, check if there are processes in the queue
            if self.queue:
                # If there are processes in the queue, dispatch the first process
                next_process_id = self.queue.pop(0)
                self.dispatcher_func(self.processes[next_process_id])

    def run(self, seed):
        super().run(seed)
        while self.current_time <= self.total_simulation_time:
            # Call the scheduler function to handle events
            self.scheduler()
            # Get the next process from the queue
            cur_process_id = None
            if self.queue:
                cur_process_id = self.queue[0]
            cur_process = self.processes[cur_process_id] if cur_process_id is not None else None
            # Call the dispatcher function to execute the process
            self.dispatcher(cur_process)
            
            # Debugging information
            print(f"Time: {self.current_time}, Queue: {self.queue}, Currently Running Process: {self.currently_running_process}")
            
            if cur_process is None:
                print("Error: Current process is None!!!")
                print(f"Queue: {self.queue}")
                print(f"Processes: {self.processes}")
                raise ValueError("Scheduler didn't select any process to run!!!")
            
            # Move time forward to the next event
            self.current_time = self.get_next_event_time()


class SJF(SchedulerDES):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = []

    def scheduler_func(self, cur_event):
        # SJF scheduling logic
        if cur_event.event_type == EventTypes.PROC_ARRIVES:
            # If a process arrives, add it to the queue based on its service time
            self.queue.append(cur_event.process_id)
            self.queue.sort(key=lambda pid: self.processes[pid].service_time)

    def dispatcher_func(self, cur_process):
        # SJF dispatching logic
        if cur_process is not None:
            # If there are processes in the queue, dispatch the first one (shortest job)
            self.log_info("Dispatching process #{}".format(cur_process.process_id))
            cur_process.process_state = ProcessStates.RUNNING
            cur_process.run_for(self.time_quantum, self.current_time)
            # Add the process to the list of completed processes
            self.completed_processes.append(cur_process)
        else:
            self.log_info("No process to dispatch.")

    def run(self, seed):
        super().run(seed)
        while self.current_time <= self.total_simulation_time:
            # Call the scheduler function to handle events
            self.scheduler()
            # Get the next process from the queue
            cur_process_id = None
            if self.queue:
                cur_process_id = self.queue.pop(0)
            cur_process = self.processes[cur_process_id] if cur_process_id is not None else None
            # Call the dispatcher function to execute the process
            self.dispatcher(cur_process)
            # Move time forward to the next event
            self.current_time = self.get_next_event_time()



  
class RR(SchedulerDES):
    def __init__(self, *args, quantum=1.0, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.time_quantum = quantum
        self.queue = []

    def scheduler_func(self, cur_event):
        # RR scheduling logic
        if cur_event.event_type == EventTypes.PROC_ARRIVES:
            # If a process arrives, add it to the end of the queue
            self.queue.append(cur_event.process_id)

    def dispatcher_func(self, cur_process):
        # RR dispatching logic
        if cur_process is not None:
            self.log_info("Dispatching process #{}".format(cur_process.process_id))
            cur_process.process_state = ProcessStates.RUNNING
            time_executed = cur_process.run_for(self.time_quantum, self.current_time)
            # Check if the process is completed or needs to be added back to the queue
            if cur_process.remaining_time > 0:
                # If the process needs more time, add it back to the end of the queue
                self.queue.append(cur_process.process_id)
            else:
                # If the process is completed, add it to the list of completed processes
                self.completed_processes.append(cur_process)
        else:
            self.log_info("No process to dispatch.")

    def run(self, seed):
        super().run(seed)
        while self.current_time <= self.total_simulation_time:
            # Call the scheduler function to handle events
            self.scheduler()
            # Get the next process from the queue
            cur_process_id = None
            if self.queue:
                cur_process_id = self.queue.pop(0)
            cur_process = self.processes[cur_process_id] if cur_process_id is not None else None
            # Call the dispatcher function to execute the process
            self.dispatcher(cur_process)
            # Move time forward to the next event
            self.current_time = self.get_next_event_time()

class SRTF(SchedulerDES):
    def scheduler_func(self, cur_event):
        # SRTF scheduling logic
        if cur_event.event_type == EventTypes.PROC_ARRIVES:
            # If a process arrives, check if it has a shorter remaining time than the currently running process
            if self.currently_running_process is not None and \
                    cur_event.process_id != self.currently_running_process.process_id and \
                    self.processes[cur_event.process_id].remaining_time < self.currently_running_process.remaining_time:
                # If the arriving process has a shorter remaining time, preempt the currently running process
                self.log_info("Preempting process #{} in favor of #{}".format(
                    self.currently_running_process.process_id, cur_event.process_id))
                self.queue.append(self.currently_running_process.process_id)
            elif self.currently_running_process is None:
                # If there is no currently running process, dispatch the arriving process
                self.queue.append(cur_event.process_id)

    def dispatcher_func(self, cur_process):
        # SRTF dispatching logic
        if cur_process is not None:
            self.log_info("Dispatching process #{}".format(cur_process.process_id))
            cur_process.process_state = ProcessStates.RUNNING
            time_executed = cur_process.run_for(cur_process.remaining_time, self.current_time)
            # Check if the process is completed
            if cur_process.remaining_time == 0:
                # If the process is completed, add it to the list of completed processes
                self.completed_processes.append(cur_process)
            else:
                # If the process is not completed, update the currently running process
                self.currently_running_process = cur_process
        else:
            self.log_info("No process to dispatch.")

    def run(self, seed):
        super().run(seed)
        while self.current_time <= self.total_simulation_time:
            # Call the scheduler function to handle events
            self.scheduler()
            # Get the next process from the queue
            cur_process_id = None
            if self.queue:
                cur_process_id = min(self.queue, key=lambda x: self.processes[x].remaining_time)
                self.queue.remove(cur_process_id)
            cur_process = self.processes[cur_process_id] if cur_process_id is not None else None
            # Call the dispatcher function to execute the process
            self.dispatcher(cur_process)
            # Move time forward to the next event
            self.current_time = self.get_next_event_time()
```

For reference, here is the code in des.py that handles the errors:

```
while self.events_queue:
            # Debug logging of events queue
            self._logger.debug("Events queue at time " + str(self.time) + ":")
            self.__log_events_queue()

            # Remove the next event to be processed from the queue
            cur_event = self.events_queue.popleft()
            self._logger.debug("Processing event: " + str(cur_event) + " at time " + str(self.time))

            # Advance internal clock and update process states, if necessary
            if self.time < cur_event.event_time:
                self._logger.debug("Advancing time to " + str(cur_event.event_time))
                self.time = cur_event.event_time
            self.__update_process_states()

            # Debug logging of process table
            self._logger.info("Processes at time " + str(self.time) + ":")
            self.__log_processes(logging.INFO)

            # Run scheduler to select next process to execute
            process_to_run = self.scheduler_func(cur_event)
            if process_to_run is None:
                raise ValueError("Scheduler didn't select any process to run!!!")
            self._logger.info(
                "Next process to run: " + str(process_to_run.process_id) + " (prev: " + str(self.process_on_cpu) + ")")
            if process_to_run.process_state != ProcessStates.READY:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Process " + str(process_to_run) + " not in runnable state (" + str(process_to_run.process_state) + ").")

            # Advance the internal clock by the context switch time, if a
            # process different than the previously executing one was selected
            if process_to_run != self.process_on_cpu:
                self.process_on_cpu = process_to_run
                self.time += self.context_switch_time
```